# How to create a Column that defaults to a ListView as fallback if the content widgets are too large?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have some widgets that I want to display on a screen.

If the screen is large enough, the widgets should be centered on it like this:

```dart
Column(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
  children: [...],
)
```

On small screens, I don't want the `Column` to overflow (black & yellow stripes) but instead, let the user scroll through them, as if they were in a `ListView`, like this:

```dart
ListView(
  children: [...],
)
```

If I knew the dimensions of the widgets beforehand, I could change the layout to one of the above in a `LayoutBuilder` based on the incoming constraints.
However, I don't know how their dimensions, so is there any easy way to achieve this on the widget layer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`SingleChildScrollView`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SingleChildScrollView-class.html) with `physics: ClampingScrollPhysics()` to avoid unwanted scrolling, wrapped in `Center` widget.

e.g.

```dart
Center(
  child: SingleChildScrollView(
    physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(), // To prevent the content from being always scrollable even when overall height is smaller than the screen.
    child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [/*...*/],
    )
  )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your column with a SingheChildScrollView and it should work for you.